# How do I enable scrolling with UITextLabel or UITextField in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I've been working on something and just when I figure one thing out I get stuck with another. I first tried using UITextLabel but I wasn't able to scroll through everything I wrote when I ran it on the simulator. I then tried in UITextField but ran into the same problem, no scrolling. Of course if I use UITextfield I need it to be un-editable. Here's what I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class ProtocolDescriptionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var protocolTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var protocolDescription: UILabel!

    var proto = ""
    var isScrollEnable = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        protocolTitle.text = proto
/* ["Atrial Fibrillation with RVR","Bradycardia/AV Blocks","Cardiac
    Arrest AED","Cardiac Arrest Asystole/PEA","Chest Pain/ACS","ICD 
    Deactivation","LVAD","PVC's with Chest Pain","PSVT","Stemi 
    Alert","Tor Medical","V-Fib/Pulseless V-Tach","Wide Complex 
    Tachycardia"]
*/

        if  proto == "Atrial Fibrillation with RVR" {
            protocolDescription.text = """
Pt must have ONE OR MORE of the following:
    ►chest pain
    ►dyspnea
    ►altered mental status
    ►hypotension
    ►ischemic changes
->Provide oxygen via nasal cannula or non-rebreather to maintain oxygen
  saturation of 93-95%, unless COPD (89-92%)
->IV NS
    ->Treat any acute underlying problems
    - ASA, NTG for chest pain—refer to Chest Pain protocol
    - NTG for pulmonary edema—refer to CHF/Pulmonary Edema protocol
    - Assess for low volume state and, if suspected, administer IV NS
    500 ml bolus
If patient remains symptomatic and rate above 120, CONTACT MEDICAL
CONTROL to discuss and give if directed:
->Magnesium Sulfate 2 gm in NS 100 ml IV infused over 2-10 minutes
"""
    }
        if proto == "Bradycardia/AV Blocks" {
        protocolDescription.text = """
Patients must have one or more of the following:
        ► Chest pain ► Hypotension ► Altered mental status
        ► Dyspnea ► Ischemic changes
->Provide oxygen via nasal cannula or non-rebreather to maintain oxygen
 saturation of 93-95%, unless COPD (89-92%)
->IV NS KVO
    -If patient is believed to be hypovolemic, administer 250ml fluid
 bolus, then re-evaluate

"""
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a `UITextLabel`. Do you mean `UILabel`?

Comment: If the text fits in the UITextView, then it won't scroll. If your constraints are not set properly (i.e., if the bottom of the textview is not constrained to bottom of the viewController.view) then it might not scroll becuz textview is expanding to fit the text. Can't help you without more info about how you setup your views/more code..

Comment: Yes I'm sorry it is UILabel. I started off by dragging a UIScrollView to the app then just a View followed by a Label. I set the constraints all to 0 and set the height to 1000. It's still not working.